# Expo Application Scroll View to view other content

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, scrollview, react-animated

Im trying to make the scroll more natural. When I scroll or click the How is my location used it just jump to the text it needs to show instead of a natural feeling.

Does anyone know how I can get this resolved?

I have tried adding Animations etc to almost every component but Im not able to get it to work as per above.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import LocationSettings from '../config/location';

const LocationPermissionScreen = () => {
  const [showMoreInfo, setShowMoreInfo] = useState(false);
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const handleAllowPress = async () => {
    const { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('locationPermission', JSON.stringify(status));
    if (status === 'granted') {
      navigation.navigate('PushNotificationScreen');
    }
    console.log('Location permission granted');
  };

  const handleMoreInfoPress = () => {
    setShowMoreInfo(!showMoreInfo);
  };
  const [previousScrollY, setPreviousScrollY] = useState(0);

  const handleScroll = (event) => {
    const currentScrollY = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
    if (previousScrollY < currentScrollY) {
      setShowMoreInfo(false);
    } else if (previousScrollY > currentScrollY) {
      setShowMoreInfo(true);
    }
    setPreviousScrollY(currentScrollY);
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeAreaContainer}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView
          contentContainerStyle={[
            styles.scrollView,
            showMoreInfo ? styles.scrollViewMoreInfo : null,
          ]}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          onScroll={handleScroll}
          scrollEventThrottle={16}
        >

          {!showMoreInfo && (
            <View style={styles.animationContainer}>
              <LottieView
                source={LocationSettings.animation}
                autoPlay
                loop
              />
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                <Text style={[styles.mainText, { marginTop: '60%' }]}>{LocationSettings.firstTitle}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.subText}>{LocationSettings.subTitle}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          )}
          {showMoreInfo && (
            <View style={styles.centeredContainer}>
              <View style={styles.moreInfo}>
                <Text style={styles.dontWorryText}>Don't Worry</Text>
                <Text style={styles.infoText}>
                  Your location is used so that we can track you when you submit a panic.
                </Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          )}
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[
              styles.allowButton,
              showMoreInfo ? styles.allowButtonTop : styles.allowButtonBottom,
            ]}
            onPress={handleAllowPress}
          >
            <LinearGradient
              colors={LocationSettings.gradient}
              start={[1, -0]}
              end={[0, -0]}
              style={styles.allowButtonGradient}
            >
              <Text style={styles.allowButtonText}>Allow</Text>
            </LinearGradient>
          </TouchableOpacity>


          <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleMoreInfoPress}>
            <Text style={styles.moreInfoLink}>
              How is my location used{' '}
              <Text>{showMoreInfo ? '▼' : '▲'}</Text>
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  safeAreaContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: LocationSettings.backgroundColor,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  scrollView: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  scrollViewMoreInfo: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
  animationContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginBottom: 75
  },
  centeredContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  moreInfo: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingVertical: 20,
  },
  dontWorryText: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: LocationSettings.textColor,
  },
  infoText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    color: LocationSettings.textColor,
    fontSize: 15,
    paddingTop: 10
  },
  mainText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 600,
    color: LocationSettings.textColor,
  },
  subText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 15,
    marginTop: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: '9%',
    color: LocationSettings.textColor,
  },
  allowButton: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 25,
    width: '90%',
  },
  allowButtonTop: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 10,
  },
  allowButtonGradient: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 25,
  },
  allowButtonText: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  moreInfoLink: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 16,
    textDecorationLine: 'underline',
    marginTop: 10,
    color: LocationSettings.textColor,
  },
});

export default LocationPermissionScreen;
```